# SELECT in WHERE clause that uses outer information

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to select all users that have an average timeout rate of less that 50%:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   user u 
WHERE  (SELECT Avg(gu.didtimeout) 
        FROM   (SELECT didtimeout 
                FROM   gameuser 
                WHERE  userid = u.userid 
                LIMIT  50) gu) < 0.5;
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'u.userID' in 'where clause'
```

How might I make this query in legal MySQL?

EDIT 1:

Here are the relevant parts of the schemas of `GameUser` and `User`.

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `userID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `GameUser` (
  `gameID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `userID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `didTimeout` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

EDIT 2:

Using MySQL 5.7.11.

Comment: Can you show the structure of your tables?\

Comment: @Cristian added

Comment: try using joins as oppose to nested selects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid  in (SELECT gu.userid 
FROM gameuser gu
GROUP BY gu.userid
HAVING AVG(gu.didtimeout) < 0.5);
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the user ids, do this:

```
SELECT gu.userid 
FROM gameuser gu
GROUP BY gu.userid
HAVING AVG(gu.didtimeout) < 0.5;
```

You can join in additional user information if that is required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, however the product of aggregate functions cannot be used in a WHERE clause, use HAVING instead.

```
SELECT Avg(gu.didtimeout) as average_timeout
FROM   user u
JOIN   gameuser gu
ON     gu.userid = u.userid
GROUP BY u.userid
HAVING  average_timeout < .5
LIMIT  50;
```